# Issue when trying to implement Joda-Time functionality in my program

Tags: java, jar, jodatime

I'm getting the following error in my program:

> DateTimeFormatter cannot be resolved to a type

at the line:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern();
```

I imported the exact class:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
```

Why exactly is it getting hosed up on "DateTimeFormatter"??

EDIT:

when changing

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern();
```

to

```
DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern();
```

I get the following error:

> The method forPattern(String) in the type DateTimeFormat is not
>   applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Is `DateTimeFormatter` the same class as `DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: @KevinO  I don't believe so.  See my above edit

Comment: Now if you use `DateTimeFormat`, [look at the Javadocs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/) which indicate that `.forPattern` takes a String of the date pattern (e.g., yyy-MM-dd or whatever). It returns a DateTimeFormatter, which must also be imported.

Comment: @KevinO  Gotcha. Thats poor documentation.  Thanks for the clarification!